# How to prevent razor from escaping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add a youtube video code dynamically to a link, however razor escapes the @ sign.

```html
//www.youtube.com/embed/@Model.MallVideos.Where( mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code
```

it work if I write it like  embed/ @Model  or embed /@Model
however now the URI is broken.

What  mean of broken html is that when the result is rendered into the browser you will see:

```html
http://www.youtube.com/embed/@Model.MallVideos.Where( mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code
```

instead of

```html
http://www.youtube.com/embed/fghnkhyth6uh
```

interestingly when I use /@model in any other place in my urls on the same view it works, its only this particular URL that acts so strangely. for refrence, this code is not in any other code block, and its directly placed into the view.

how can I force razor to let me do this task without a need for creating a custom function, or extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses to be explicit about what the expression is, as described in [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/@(Model.MallVideos.Where( mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code)
```

**HTML Extension Method**

```
public static MvcHtmlString FullUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string baseAddress,
    string relativeUri,
    string innerText = "")
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri(baseAddress);
    Uri fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri);

    var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
    builder.MergeAttribute("href", fullUri.ToString());

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
    {
        builder.InnerHtml = fullUri.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        builder.InnerHtml = innerText;
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

**cshtml**

```
    @Html.FullUrl(
        "http://www.youtube.com/embed/",
        Model.MallVideos.Where( mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code)
```

**resulting Html**

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/12345">http://www.youtube.com/embed/12345</a>
```

---

I have tried to reproduce your issue and I'm not able to reproduce it when I use the parentheses.

**Models**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class VideosViewModel
    {
        public List<MallVideo> MallVideos { get; set; }
    }

    public class MallVideo
    {
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public Video Video { get; set; }
    }

    public class Video
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new VideosViewModel();
        model.MallVideos = GetVideos(10);

        return View(model);
    }

    public List<MallVideo> GetVideos(int length)
    {
        var videos = new List<MallVideo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            videos.Add(new MallVideo()
            {
                IsFeatured = (rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5),
                Video = new Video()
                {
                    Code = Path.GetRandomFileName()
                }
            });
        }

        return videos;
    }
}
```

**View**

*note: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/@(Model.MallVideos.Where(mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code)`*

```
@model Project.Models.VideosViewModel

<fieldset>
    <legend>VideosViewModel</legend>
    <p>
        http://www.youtube.com/embed/@(Model.MallVideos.Where(mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Model.MallVideos.Where(mv => mv.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().Video.Code
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

**Resulting Html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>VideosViewModel</legend>
    <p>
        http://www.youtube.com/embed/013dq0j5.dr1
    </p>
    <p>
        013dq0j5.dr1
    </p>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work. It just ignores it and put the code as HTML into the browser.
I ended up using String.concat to attach the razore result to the end of the string, but I am still hoping razor has a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "code as HTML into the browser", could you paste an example of the expected result and actual?  There may be better solutions based on what it is you want, for example you might decide that an extension method would be appropriate, I have updated my answer with an extension method.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMartin, I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Today I was able to do:

(in the context of spitting out something into an inline javascript)

```js
var someSortfData = '@Html.Raw(Model.SomeSortOfData)';
```

in case you landed here wondering how to prevent the output being escaped at all.